# Angularjs - can't pass variable to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the code below. `predictions['Team1 expected goals']` comes up as `undefined` in the donutChart.js directive even though the value is defined on the second line. How do I properly pass that to the directive?

```
<div>
  <div>{{ (fixture.team1.name.short_name || fixture.team1.name.gsm_name) }}</div>
  <div>{{ predictions['Team1 expected goals'] | number : 2  }}</div>
</div>
<div>
  <donut-chart team1="predictions['Team1 expected goals']" 
               team2="predictions['Team2 expected goals']">
  </donut-chart>
</div>
```

The below works as expected:

```
<donut-chart team1="1.26" team2="0.81"></donut-chart>
```

Here is the code for the donutChart.js directive. Note also that the structure is, an overall controller calls a directive (called models-prices) which calls this chart directive.

```
angular.module('stratabet')
.directive('donutChart', function(appVersion) {
  'use strict';

  var directive = {
    priority: 0,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      team1: '=',
      team2: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log('donutChart controller - team1: ' + $scope.team1 + ', team2: ' + $scope.team2);
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('donutChart - team1: ' + scope.tea1 + ', team2: ' + scope.team2);
}
}
```

Comment: That sure looks like CSS for some reason.

Comment: it's in the html template: http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the predictions part in curly braces, like {{predictions['...']}} ?

Comment: @user1387717, what is `<donut-chart>` or `donutChart.js`? Please make clear which external library you are using

Comment: It's not an external library - added the code in donutChart.js above

Answer (score 0):

In the line,

```
console.log('donutChart - team1: ' + scope.tea1 + ', team2: ' + scope.team2);
```

there is  a typo in **scope.tea1**, it should be **$scope.team1** as there is no property tea1 on scope

it should be

```
console.log('donutChart - team1: ' + scope.team1 + ', team2: ' + scope.team2);
```